# How do I make multiple tap handlers per row in an iOS TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a list of businesses in a tableview with a few clickable areas. The first is an area to view business details on a separate ViewController, the second is to phone the business, and the third is to locate the business on a map.

I'm new to iOS so I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

In Android, it's fairly easy. I can do something like this in the getView() method in the table adapter:

```
linearLayoutBusiness.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("business", business);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

What I have so far is this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
    //business details tap handler
    UITapGestureRecognizer *touchOnBusinessDetails = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detailsTapHandler)];
    [cell.BusinessInfoView addGestureRecognizer:touchOnBusinessDetails];


    //call view tap handler
    UITapGestureRecognizer *touchOnCallView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callViewTapHandler)];
    [cell.callView addGestureRecognizer:touchOnCallView];

    //location view tap handler
    UITapGestureRecognizer *touchOnLocationView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationViewTapHandler)];
    [cell.locationView addGestureRecognizer:touchOnLocationView];


    return cell;
}

- (void)detailsTapHandler{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSInteger row = selectedIndexPath.row;
    BusinessEntity *businessTapped = businesses[row];

    //open details view
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailsSegue" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"detailsView");
}

- (void)callViewTapHandler{
    NSLog(@"callView");
}

- (void)locationViewTapHandler{
    NSLog(@"locationView");
}
```

The problem I have run into is the selectedIndexPath is always nil, and I can't send the business object corresponding with the selected row in the detailsTapHandler method.

Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors should look like:

```
- (void)locationViewTapHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"locationView");
}
```

So when selector gets triggered, it is passed gesture recognizer as an argument. Then you can use `sender.view` property to access view attached to the gesture recognizer.

Knowing the view, you can either crawl up the view hierarchy to get the `UITableViewCell` containing it, and then call `[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]`, or just store model index in the view's `tag` property and access model directly by index.

Comment: Do I need to explicitly send the UIGestureRecognizer as an argument? Or is it done automatically? I'm getting a Invalid argument exception: `uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BrowseViewController detailsTapHandler]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa2506da9f0'`

Comment: No, it will be sent automatically. You need to adjust your selector signature by adding a colon, because it is expected to have an argument now: `initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationViewTapHandler:)`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It works perfectly. I added `NSInteger cellRow = indexPath.row; cell.BusinessInfoView.tag = cellRow;` into the numberOfRowsInSection method and `NSInteger cellRow = sender.view.tag;`  in the detailsTapHandler method.